# Open new ssh session via existing ssh -N session

Tags: linux, ssh, security

Assume that I have an ssh tunnel running in the background, e.g.:

```
ssh -L 1478:localhost:1478 admin@m1 -N
```

And I want to connect to `m1`, however, in the time between starting the tunnel and now, I've lost the ability to ssh into the machine (the tunnel, however, is still working).

Is there a way to use the existing tunnel to ssh into the machine (as in, open a console that sends commands to that machine as the user `admin`).

I know this would be trivial if I opened the tunnel without the `-N` argument, but I'm unsure if it can be done when opening tunnels this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by **lost the ability to ssh**, you meant lost access to credentials, like expired `ssh-agent` identities or `rm -rf`-ed private keys, then yes you can still log-in to the host, iff tunnel's ssh connection was opened with `ControlMaster` option. The `ControlMaster` option let you reuse existing SSH master session socket without re-authenticating for every new session you want to open.

HTH

Comment: The `ControlMaster` option wasn't set at the time of opening the tunnels.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know of any other mechanism that could prevent authentication and still provide you with access to the host, assuming that's the intent.

Comment: That is the intent, thanks for the suggestion anyway.